# Rectangle with sides $x$ and $y$.

Tags: divisibility, integers

Consider a rectangle with integer sides $x$ and $y$ and area $A = xy$. If we increase one side by 1 unit and the other by 2, the area of the new rectangle is doubled.
Find the length of the sides of the original rectangle.

> My attempt: The original rectangle has area $A = xy$. The new rectangle has sides $x+1$ and $y+2$. Since we have a symmetry in $x$ and $y$, it is indifferent which side is increased by 1 unit or 2.
> So the new area is $(x+1)\cdot(y+2) = 2A = 2xy$.

> Solving by $y$, we get $y=2\left(\,{\frac{x+1}{x-1}}\,\right)$, $x>1$.

> This is a hyperbola which has 3 integer pairs of solutions: (x,y) = (3,4), (2,6) and (5,3).
> These seem to be the only solutions. Is there any way to solve this, other than trial and error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $y = \dfrac {2(x+1)}{x-1} = 2+\dfrac 4{x-1}$, we just need to determine when $\dfrac 4 {x-1}$ is an integer.

This amounts to checking all factors of $4$.

Comment: player3236 thank you!